# I cannot get new line in python

Tags: python

my code:

```
question_prompts = [
    "What color are apples?]\n(a) Red/Green \n(b) Yellow \n(c) Purple\n\n",
]
print(question_prompts)
```

`\n` in this array `[]` didn't work. It cannot be down a new line. Hope to get your help

Comment: Get first element of the list and print, ```print(question_prompts[0])```

Comment: you mean get a line  from keyboard?

Comment: Use `input` function with and `str` variable to ask the user to enter a answer to you question (the color of apples).

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are printing the list and not the string whose inside the list, try this:

```
question_prompts = [
    "What color are apples?]\n(a) Red/Green \n(b) Yellow \n(c) Purple\n\n",
]

for prompt in question_prompts:
    print(prompt)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you are printing the whole of `question_prompts` which just shows you what is in the whole of that array without getting a new line.

You need to specifically print the first element:

```
>>> print(question_prompts[0])
What color are apples?]
(a) Red/Green 
(b) Yellow 
(c) Purple
```

To print all the elements:

```
for prompt in question_prompts:
    print(prompt)
```

Comment: Thank you, but how can I print more than one element in array:

Comment: just like that: question_prompts = [
    "What color are apples?]\n(a) Red/Green \n(b) Yellow \n(c) Purple\n\n",
    "What color are bananas?\n(a) Red/Green \n(b) Yellow \n(c) Purple\n\n",
    "What color are strawberries?\n(a) Red \n(b) Yellow \n(c) Purple\n\n"
]
print(question_prompts)

Comment: `for prompt in question_prompts:
    print(prompt)`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to print the items separately, as follows:

```
question_prompts = ["What color are apples?", "(a) Red / Green", "(b) Yellow", "(c) Purple"]

for item in question_prompts:
    print(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the string is inside a list, it does not print properly..

You can use

```py
for q in question_prompts:
    print(q)
```

and you should see the newlines

Answer (score 0):

It would be easy to work with if you use a dictionary for your options instead.

```
question = "What color are apples?"
options  = {'a': 'Red/Green', 'b': 'Yellow', 'c': 'Purple'}

print(question)
for option in "abcd":
 print(f'({option}) {options[option]}')
```